# Can you find the number of people at this party?

Tags: combinatorics

At a party everyone was shaking hands with others. In all, there were 66 handshakes. Now find the number of people at this party.

Note:- You may choose to read the solution below.

Comment: Before downvoting, note that he has self answered below.

Comment: Do not downvote, please ! The OP answered his question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{(n\times (n-1))}{2}= 66$

Now,we have to solve the equation.

$n\times(n-1)= 132$

$n^2 - n = 132$

Now, the only number that satisfies this condition is 12. Hence, the answer is $\boxed{12}$.

Comment: What if there were $-11$ people ;)

Comment: It was a joke, I said $-11$ people :P. (Note: I am not a very funny person)

Comment: Why am I getting 2 down votes for this question?

Comment: I believe the downvoters didn't notice your self answer, and saw a question that appeared to be without any effort.

Comment: @AnujShikarkhane, you should perhaps add a note *in your question* saying you're attempting to answer your own question below. It also would be interesting a *little* explanation as why the formula $\;\frac{n(n-1)}2=66\;$ (why the sum of the first $\;n-1\;$ natural numbers solve the problem). Anyway, +1